# Why can't I get the database lastrowid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to record form data and pass it to the another page, so I was just going to pass it the (autoincrementing) row id and then retrieve it in the next function. It is properly creating the database entry, but the cursor `lastrowid` is always returning `None`, so I can't get the data for the next page.

```
def connect_db():
    """Connects to the database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv


def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.route('/choose', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def input_values():
    form = UserValuesForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        g.db = get_db()
        g.db.execute('insert into requests (occupants, '
                   'transmission_type, drive_type, engine_type, fuel_economy, '
                   'trunk_capacity, towing_capacity, safety_rating) '
                   'values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   [form.occupants.data, ';'.join(form.transmission_type.data),
                    ';'.join(form.drive_type.data), ';'.join(form.engine_type.data),
                    form.fuel_economy.data, form.trunk_capacity.data,
                    form.towing_capacity.data, form.safety_rating.data])
        g.last_req_id = g.db.cursor().lastrowid
        g.db.commit()
        return redirect('results/{0}'.format(str(g.last_req_id)))
    return render_template('choose.html', form=form)

@app.route('/results/<int:req_id>', methods=['GET'])
def result(req_id):
    return render_template('results.html')
```

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to get the value from a brand new cursor. You want to perform your insert with the same cursor you get the value from.

```
cursor = g.db.cursor()
cursor.execute('...')
g.last_req_id = cursor.lastrowid
g.db.commit()
```

Also, you don't need to associate `last_req_id` with `g` since all you do is use it locally within `input_values`.

```
last_req_id = cursor.lastrowid
return redirect('results/{0}'.format(last_req_id))
```

You'll also see that I removed the call to `str`. `format` will handle that for you.

Comment: Unless its a restriction in Python's bindings, the last row id is indeed available before a commit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused because the database connection g.db had the execute method I needed to make an entry, so I didn't realize I needed to explicitly create the cursor object.